# Can an `ElementVisitor` be used to traverse the statements in the body of a method?

Tags: java, reflection, annotations, annotation-processing

I'm trying to make a custom annotation that checks to see if a certain method is called in a method's body annotated with it. Something like:

```java
@TypeQualifierDefault(ElementType.METHOD)
@Retention(RetentionPolicy.SOURCE)
@interface MutatingMethod {
}

interface Mutable {
  void preMutate();
  void postMutate();
  // other methods
}
```

And then within a certain `Mutable` class we would have:

```java
class Structure<T> implements Mutable {
  @MutatingMethod
  void add(T data) {
    preMutate();
    // actual mutation code
    postMutate();
  }
}
```

I want to be able to get warnings of some sort if the body of a method like `add` that is annotated with `@MutatingMethod` *does not* include calls to `preMutate` and `postMutate`. Can an [`ElementVisitor`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/javax/lang/model/element/ElementVisitor.html) (`javax.lang.model.element.ElementVisitor`) be used to traverse the (possibly obfuscated) statements and method calls in the body of a method? If so what would that look like? If not what else can I use?

Just to clarify, I know this is impossible (or more difficult) to accomplish in runtime via bytecode decompilation, so this annotation is meant to only work during compilation **via reflection** (`java.lang.reflect.*` and `javax.lang.model.*`) and is not retained in class files.

You are free to modify the code however you want to get it to work, for example by introducing a new annotation called `@MutableType` that `Structure` and any other `Mutable` types must be annotated with it for this to work.

A cherry on top would be to assert that `preMutate` is called before `postMutate` and not after.

It shouldn't matter but I'm using Gradle and the IntelliJ IDEA IDE.

Any help is greatly appreciated; material on this is strangely scarce and/or inadequate on the web. I have been using publicly available sources to learn about this!

Comment: Are you bound to Java 8? And where does `@TypeQualifierDefault` come from and what does it do?

Comment: @Holger `@TypeQualifierDefault` and `@Retention` are Java's own annotations used to annotate custom annotations. No I am not bound to Java 8.

Comment: I don’t see any `@TypeQualifierDefault` in the Java API. Do you mean [`@Target`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/17/docs/api/java.base/java/lang/annotation/Target.html)?

Comment: @Holger It's a part of [JSR305](https://jcp.org/en/jsr/detail?id=305), [here is a link](https://www.javadoc.io/doc/com.google.code.findbugs/jsr305/latest/javax/annotation/meta/TypeQualifierDefault.html).

Comment: Well that’s not “Java's own annotations” but a project that unfortunately died a decade ago. After reading the `@TypeQualifierDefault`’s description, “*to denote that the annotation defines a default type qualifier that is visible within the scope of the element it is applied to*”, I still have no idea what it is supposed to do. From your problem description, I can conclude that `@Target(ElementType.METHOD)` would make sense. The other annotation, I don’t know.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There are two modules,

- [`java.compiler`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/17/docs/api/java.compiler/module-summary.html) which contains [the API for annotation processors](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/17/docs/api/java.compiler/javax/annotation/processing/package-summary.html) and the simple abstraction you have already discovered.

  The `ElementVisitor` abstraction does not support digging into the method’s code.
- The [`jdk.compiler`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/17/docs/api/jdk.compiler/module-summary.html) module, containing an extended API originally not considered to be part of the standard API and hence not included in the official API documentation prior to the introduction of the module system.

  This API allows analyzing the syntax tree of the currently compiled source code.

When your starting point is an annotation processor, you should have a [`ProcessingEnvironment`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/17/docs/api/java.compiler/javax/annotation/processing/ProcessingEnvironment.html) which was given to your [`init`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/17/docs/api/java.compiler/javax/annotation/processing/Processor.html#init(javax.annotation.processing.ProcessingEnvironment)) method. Then, you can invoke [`Trees.instance(ProcessingEnvironment)`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/17/docs/api/jdk.compiler/com/sun/source/util/Trees.html#instance(javax.annotation.processing.ProcessingEnvironment)) to get a helper object which has the method [`getTree(Element)`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/17/docs/api/jdk.compiler/com/sun/source/util/Trees.html#getTree(javax.lang.model.element.Element)) you can use to get the syntax tree element. Then, you can traverse the syntax tree from there.

Most of these classes documented in the JDK 17 API do already exist in earlier versions (you might notice the “since 1.6”) even when not present in the older documentation. But prior to JDK 9 you have to include the `lib/tools.jar` of the particular JDK into your classpath when compiling the annotation processor.

###### <sub>(when writing a modular annotation processor)</sub>

```java
import javax.annotation.processing.Processor;

module anno.proc.example {
    requires jdk.compiler;
    provides Processor with anno.proc.example.MyProcessor;
}
```

```java
package anno.proc.example;

import java.util.*;

import javax.annotation.processing.*;
import javax.lang.model.element.TypeElement;
import javax.tools.Diagnostic;

import com.sun.source.tree.*;
import com.sun.source.tree.Tree.Kind;
import com.sun.source.util.Trees;

import javax.lang.model.SourceVersion;
import javax.lang.model.element.Element;

@SupportedSourceVersion(SourceVersion.RELEASE_17) // adapt when using older version
@SupportedAnnotationTypes(MyProcessor.ANNOTATION_NAME)
public class MyProcessor extends AbstractProcessor {
    static final String ANNOTATION_NAME = "my.example.MutatingMethod";
    static final String REQUIRED_FIRST = "preMutate", REQUIRED_LAST = "postMutate";

    // the inherited method does already store the processingEnv
    // public void init(ProcessingEnvironment processingEnv) {

    @Override
    public boolean process(Set<? extends TypeElement> annotations, RoundEnvironment roundEnv) {
        Optional<? extends TypeElement> o = annotations.stream()
            .filter(e -> ANNOTATION_NAME.contentEquals(e.getQualifiedName())).findAny();
        if(!o.isPresent()) return false;
        TypeElement myAnnotation = o.get();

        roundEnv.getElementsAnnotatedWith(myAnnotation).forEach(this::check);

        return true;
    }

    private void check(Element e) {
        Trees trees = Trees.instance(processingEnv);
        Tree tree = trees.getTree(e);
        if(tree.getKind() != Kind.METHOD) { // should not happen as compiler handles @Target
            processingEnv.getMessager()
                .printMessage(Diagnostic.Kind.ERROR, ANNOTATION_NAME + " only allowed at methods", e);
            return;
        }
        MethodTree m = (MethodTree) tree;
        List<? extends StatementTree> statements = m.getBody().getStatements();
        if(statements.isEmpty() || !isRequiredFirst(statements.get(0))) {
            processingEnv.getMessager()
                .printMessage(Diagnostic.Kind.MANDATORY_WARNING,
                    "Mutating method does not start with " + REQUIRED_FIRST + "();", e);
        }
        // open challenges:
        //   - accept a return statement after postMutate();
        //   - allow a try { body } finally { postMutate(); }
        if(statements.isEmpty() || !isRequiredLast(statements.get(statements.size() - 1))) {
            processingEnv.getMessager()
                .printMessage(Diagnostic.Kind.MANDATORY_WARNING,
                    "Mutating method does not end with " + REQUIRED_LAST + "();", e);
        }
    }

    private boolean isRequiredFirst(StatementTree st) {
        return invokes(st, REQUIRED_FIRST);
    }

    private boolean isRequiredLast(StatementTree st) {
        return invokes(st, REQUIRED_LAST);
    }

    // check whether tree is an invocation of a no-arg method of the given name
    private boolean invokes(Tree tree, String method) {
        if(tree.getKind() != Kind.EXPRESSION_STATEMENT) return false;
        tree = ((ExpressionStatementTree)tree).getExpression();
        if(tree.getKind() != Kind.METHOD_INVOCATION) return false;

        MethodInvocationTree i = (MethodInvocationTree)tree;

        if(!i.getArguments().isEmpty()) return false; // not a no-arg method

        ExpressionTree ms = i.getMethodSelect();
        // TODO add support for explicit this.method()
        return ms.getKind() == Kind.IDENTIFIER
                && method.contentEquals(((IdentifierTree)ms).getName());
    }
}
```

Comment: This looks very promising but I have three questions, 1) does `@SupportedSourceVersion(SourceVersion.RELEASE_17)` basically mean it does not work in lower versions like 11 or 8? 2) are there any alternatives to the `com.sun.*` types used here and 3) what other code/configurations must there be for this to actually work and start processing the project and issuing warnings like normal IntelliJ inspections?

Comment: As the comment behind it says, you can change `@SupportedSourceVersion` to the version you need. You just get a warning when your supported version is older than the language level you’re currently compiling with. There is no alternative to these `com.sun.*` types, as said in the answer, they are part of the standard now. The steps to integrate them are the same as for any other annotation processor. Maybe this is a good starting point https://www.jetbrains.com/help/idea/annotation-processors-support.html

Answer (score -1):

Annotation processors only process declarations, not bytecode. They can not be used to make assertions about the content of a method.

If it is important to you that these methods are always called, you may want to enforce this with a proxy rather than having boilerplate code in each method. For instance, you could use a bytecode engineering library such as Javassist to add the calls at runtime:

```
var f = new ProxyFactory();
f.setSuperclass(Foo.class);
f.setFilter(m -> m.isAnnotationPresent(MutatingMethod.class));
Class c = f.createClass();
Foo foo = c.newInstance();
((Proxy)foo).setHandler((self, m, proceed, args) -> {
    self.preMutate();
    proceed.invoke(self, args);
    self.postMutate();
});

foo.setName("Peter"); // automatically calls preMutate and postMutate()
```

(code untested, since I don't have an IDE at hand)

Then, the methods are always called in the proper order, as long as you control the creation of the objects in question (which you can sort of enforce by making the super class `abstract`).