# How do I get the directory of the 'input' source files in an annotation processor?

Tags: java, annotations, annotation-processing

I want to get the directories of the source files which are getting compiled after annotation processing *while* doing the annotation processing without relying on directory/build tool conventions.

```java
public class MyProcessor extends AbstractProcessor {

  @Override
  public boolean process(Set<? extends TypeElement> annotations, RoundEnvironment roundEnv) {
    // Get the directories with source files to be compiled here
    // For example, I should be able to find all classes which I obtain via the following in the directories I want:
    roundEnv.getElementsAnnotatedWith(MyAnnotation.class)
  }
}
```

I have tried:

1. A relative path which I got with `Paths.get(".")`. But not only would I still have to rely on directory/build tool conventions to get to the source directories, it also doesn't work when the build is started from anywhere else but the project root.
2. Checking all properties in `System.getProperties()` and `System.getenv()` to see if there is anything useful being set.
3. Checked `javax.lang.model.element.TypeElement`, `javax.lang.model.type.TypeMirror` and the corresponding utility methods to see if I can get an instance's location (Did I miss something?)
4. Checked various combinations of `StandardJavaFileManager`'s methods, some of which suggest to return what I want, but returning either null/empty collections or throwing exceptions for module related parameters. Example: `standardJavaFileManager.list(StandardLocation.SOURCE_PATH, "", Set.of(Kind.SOURCE), true)`.

// edit

I'm trying to create a functionality where classes can be picked up based on super-types. For that, I created an Annotation where I can specify these super-types. I now need to scan all source files to check for classes that are sub-types of X, for which I am using a library. Said library needs to be pointed to a directory containing the classes to scan, which is why I need the source folder.

Comment: Why do you want to do this?

Comment: @JustanotherJavaprogrammer
I am using [javaparser](https://github.com/javaparser/javaparser) to derive the generated classes from the source classes. For this, javaparser needs the directory of the source file(s) so it knows what to parse.

Are you aware how much of a meme this question is, as a first comment, on this site? Imo not helpful.

Comment: Understanding the reason behind gives an opportunity to find other solutions.

Comment: did you also try to work with the `Filer` that you get from `processingEnvironment.getFiler()` instead of the `StandardJavaFileManager` ?

Comment: @cyberbrain yes, that is my current implementation. I am creating a dummy file via the `Filer`, then traverse up the directory structure until I find `src/main/java`.

Comment: I thought that you could try the `processEnvironment.getFiler().getResource()` with the `StandardLocation.SOURCE_PATH` but while I'm typing this I just thought: OK, you probably don't know a filename aka resource name to ask for, right?

Comment: Is your annotation processor actually processing annotations or are you trying to get the source code of classes not even containing your annotation?

Comment: @cyberbrain correct.

Comment: @Holger see the edit of the question.

Comment: When you can live with being bound to the JDK provided compiler, i.e. `javac`, in other words, do not need `ecj` compatibility, you can go the route of [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/70768344/2711488). The crucial part is the `Trees trees = Trees.instance(processingEnv);` which only works in that environment. Once you have the `Trees` instance, you can use `JavaFileObject sourceFile = trees.getPath(e).getCompilationUnit() .getSourceFile();` for an `Element` (like when iterating over `roundEnv.getRootElements()`). Then, you can not only invoke `toUri()` but also `getCharContent(…)`…

Comment: @Holger thank you for you input, I did check it out. Your suggestion is indeed better in terms of not relying on directory conventions, but I am not sure I want to depend on a specific compiler. Mainly due to things like GraalVM, even if they are currently compatible (didn't bother to check).

Also, the provided visitor API is honestly horrible to use, even for simple things. For example, `ClassTree` provides no build-in way of getting the qualified name. Meaning after `ClassTree.getExtendsClause()`, I'd have to check the imports for a match to get a qualified name.

Comment: Since you wrote that you want to modify the AST (in an earlier revision of the question), I suspected that this tree API isn’t suitable. I only mentioned it because it has a way to get hands on the `JavaFileObject` which allows to identify the actual file location or reading the character content directly. Still, it makes sense if the AST node, representing the *syntax* also contains the simple name if `extends` is followed by a simple name. You could use `Tree ext = ((ClassTree)trees.getTree(e)) .getExtendsClause(); if(ext != null){ TypeMirror t=trees.getTypeMirror(trees.getPath( cu, ext));`

Comment: @Holger Sorry about the quick revisions, I realized that the problem I described first could be solved without solving the 'analyzing' aspect. I guess I expected to have missed something as the source dir feels like an information that would be (easily) availabe... thanks again, though

Comment: What does “where classes can be picked up based on super-types” actually mean?